# Paired Delimeter Matching

Tags: python, stack, delimiter

I would like to write a class that will return true if and only if the expression entered contains only correctly matching delimiters such as " (), <>, [], {} " What I have written thus far will do exactly that.

```
delim_openers = '{([<'
delim_closers = '})]>'

def check_delimiters(expr):
    val = Stack()
    for c in expr:
        if c == (any(x) for x in delim_openers):
            val.push(c)
        elif c == (any(y) for y in delim_closers):
            try:
                val.pop()
            except:
                return False
    return val.empty()
```

I am a little confused however if I were test this case against specific cases such as the one below, it'll return true when I assumed it would return False, my stack shouldn't be popping the delimiter in this case. Test case:

```
from unittest import TestCase
tc = TestCase()
tc.assertFalse(check_delimiters('[ ( ] )'))
tc.assertFalse(check_delimiters('((((((( ))))))'))
```

How might I edit the `check_delimiters' method to correctly return False in these scenarios? The stacks first-in-last-out capability tends to confuse me. Also here's the stack class code in case anything else is confusing.

```
class Stack:
    class Node:
        def __init__(self, val, next=None):
            self.val = val
            self.next  = next

    def __init__(self):
        self.top = None

    def push(self, val):
        self.top = Stack.Node(val, self.top)

    def pop(self):
        assert self.top, 'Stack is empty'
        val = self.top.val
        self.top = self.top.next
        return val

    def peek(self):
        return self.top.val if self.top else None

    def empty(self):
        return self.top == None

    def __bool__(self):
        return not self.empty()

    def __repr__(self):
        if not self.top:
            return ''
        return '--> ' + ', '.join(str(x) for x in self)

    def __iter__(self):
        n = self.top
        while n:
            yield n.val
            n = n.next
```

Comment: For starters, you do not check whether the delim_closer you encounter matches the popped opener...

Comment: The comparisons are rather meaningless. `c == (any(x) for x in delim_openers)` is comparing a string to a generator. I think you mean `c in delim_openers`.

Comment: `any` doesn't work like that.

Answer (score 0):

No need for `any`, a simple contains-check will suffice. Then you have to check whether the `closer` matches the `opener`, otherwise you are just checking whether closers and openers are equal in numbers and that the closers never take the lead count-wise:

```
class Stack(list):
    push = list.append
    def peek(self):
        return self[-1] if self else None
    # ...

match = dict(zip('{([<', '})]>'))  # dict makes the matching check faster
delim_openers = set(match.keys())  # set makes the 'in' check faster
delim_closers = set(match.values())

def check_delimiters(expr):
    val = Stack()
    for c in expr:
        if c in delim_openers:
            val.push(c)
        elif c in delim_closers:
            try:
                assert match[val.pop()] == c
                # fails if stack is empty or brackets don't match
            except:
                return False
    return not val

> check_delimiters('[ ( ] )')
False
> check_delimiters('[ ( ) ]')
True
```